# Laravel Error: Call to undefined method class::seeJsonStructure()

Tags: laravel, phpunit

do i need to use some namespaces or something?
here's the code:

```
$response = $this->call('POST', 'admin/apps/list', []);
$this->seeJsonStructure([...]);
```

Comment: need more information. what's the error message and which structure you provided.

Comment: @caoglish error msg:There was 1 error:

1) a::testExample
Error: Call to undefined method a::seeJsonStructure()    ;and    the structure code is sure right.

Comment: which TestCase you extends? which laravel version?

Comment: Maybe, ```$this->seeJson()``` ?

Comment: Laravel 5.1 did not have seeJsonStructure, only since 5.2

Comment: @caoglish thx,my version too low

Comment: @JinAazoe no worry, I will post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seeJsonStructure` is not available until Laravel 5.2.

You need to upgrade the Laravel version to 5.2.

Since Laravel 5.4, it has been renamed to `assertJsonStructure()`.

Comment: I have laravel 5.4 installed but I'm getting the same issue. I'm quite new to TDD. Appreciate your input.

Comment: Found the issue. In 5.4 `seeJsonStructure()` has been replaced by `assertJsonStructure()`. Silly me :)